# onSelectionChange getting called twice in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to attach `onSelectionChange` event on `select` as follows:

```
   <mat-form-field class="full-width languageDiv" appearance="outline" *ngIf="languages && selectedLanguage">
          <mat-label>Language</mat-label>
          <mat-select [(value)]="selectedLanguage">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language" (onSelectionChange)="onLangChange($event)">
              {{language}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Here is the `onLangChange` method

```
 onLangChange(e) {
    console.log(e);
        const languageSelected = e.source.value;
        if( this.selectedLanguage !== languageSelected){

            this.selectedLanguage = (languageSelected);

        }
  }
```

Here is the `stackblitz` link:
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-otmzch)

For every change in selection, `onLangChange` is getting called twice which is messing up my other logic (not mentioned here to keep the code simple). Why is this getting called twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ngModel with ngModelChange as follows, The reason being is that you are using onSelectionChange on mat-option, while it should be on the mat-select. It is always better to go with ngModelChange as shown below,

```
 <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage" (ngModelChange)="onLangChange($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language">
        {{language}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**[DEMO STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pb5se2?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot. The `stackblitz` link you have attached doesn't work though, it has the previous code only.

Comment: I am curious, you said "*it is always better to use `ngModelChanges`*" - **why**? The official documentation suggests using **`selectionChange`**.

Comment: Note this isn't an option in Angular 7 to use on a single control when the rest of the form is using reactive forms approach.

Answer (score 0):

2 events are fired with a difference in a key value named ***isUserInput*** with boolean value.

**true**, if it is selection event

**false**, if it is deselection event

In your function, try to add an if condition like below

```
onLangChange(e) {
    console.log(e);
    if (e.isUserInput) { // isUserInput is true
        const languageSelected = e.source.value;
        if( this.selectedLanguage !== languageSelected){

            this.selectedLanguage = (languageSelected);

        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by triggering `(selectionChange)=""` within `<mat-select>` and not within the option.

```
<mat-select [compareWith]="routeCompare" formControlName="route_id" (selectionChange)="setFuelSurcharge($event)">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let route of this.routes " [value]="route.id">
            {{route.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend answer of @Sajeetharan. ( To prevent same selection, [compareWith](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/select/api))

Based on sample code on top, event value of `onLangChange($event)` has a value for indicate panel open or not.(in my sample code, ir renamed as `onSelectionChange($event)` )
So, if you need allow same option selected,
Refer this, [Trigger event on re-selecting same value on mat-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53286795/trigger-event-on-re-selecting-same-value-on-mat-select).

[Demo for this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-catch-same-choice)